# What UserAgent is reported by the WebBrowser control?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, webbrowser-control, user-agent

Just wondering what browser type the VB.NET reads as when it visits a webpage. For instance on my website it shows a break down of all the different browsers that accessed my site.

Comment: Is this when you do a Web Request?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't provide much context to your question, but I assume that you're talking about the [User Agent string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537503.aspx) that's sent when you use the [`WebBrowser` control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) built into the .NET Framework.

**Because that control just uses Internet Explorer to render the page, you'll see a User Agent string very similar to what you'd find if you visited the page using IE on the same computer.** The IE string generically reports itself as `Mozilla/4.0 compatible`, but also gives the specific version of MSIE and lists the current version of Windows.

For example, running under the 64-bit version of Windows Server 2008 R2 with version 4.0 of the .NET Framework, I'm identified as follows whenever I surf to pages from the `WebBrowser` control:

> Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1)

By contrast, Internet Explorer on the same machine displays this as the User Agent string:

> Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1)

The only difference being that the .NET `WebBrowser` control reports itself as Internet Explorer version 7.0 (`MSIE 7.0`), instead of version 8.0 that is installed on the machine. This is because the control uses the IE 7 rendering engine, rather than the one in IE 8, for compatibility reasons. If you want, you can [change this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2009/03/10/more-ie8-extensibility-improvements.aspx) by editing a registry value.

To run a `WebBrowser` control in IE8 Standards Mode, use the following new value into the registry:

> [(HKEY_CURRENT_USER or HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE)\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION] 
>   "MyApplication.exe" = dword 8000 (Hex: 0x1F40)

To run in IE7 Standards Mode, use the following registry value:

> [(HKEY_CURRENT_USER or HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE)\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION] 
>   "MyApplication.exe" = dword 7000 (Hex: 0x1B58)

Comment: This is brilliant! Helped me right away. I am wondering if there is **any other way** than editing registry?

Comment: This link: ttp://blog.notfaqs.com/2013/05/net-get-user-agent-string-of-webbrowser.html helped me get the details at runtime. The meaningful properties for the navigator object seemed to be userAgent, appCodeName, appName, appVersion, and platform.

Comment: @wpfwannabe, you can using [X-UA-Compatible](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533876%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which will make webbrowser using the right Document Mode to rendering the page. The User Agent string unfortunately wouldn't be changed by the X-UA-Compatible itself, we have to use a hack to replace the Agent string on the client side using JavaScript. But no registry key change  required.